# Not able to delete image file after image conversion from PNG to TIF

Tags: java, bufferedimage, tiff

I am creating .PNG file using `BufferedImage` with some test. Now after creating image I am trying to convert .PNG image to .TIF, which is working fine. Now once I create TIF image, I want to delete PNG image. But because of some reason, I am not able to do this. There is no any exception for this.

Here is my code

```
File pngFile = null;
FileOutputStream fOut = null;
try {
    pngFile = new File("C:\\Test.PNG");
    fOut = new FileOutputStream ("C:\\Test.TIF");
    RenderedOp src = JAI.create("fileload", "C:\\Test.PNG");
    TIFFImageEncoder encoder = new TIFFImageEncoder (fOut, null);
    encoder.encode (src);
}catch(Exception e) {
}finally {
    fOut.close();
    System.out.println(pngFile.delete());
}
```

Comment: What is JAI ? I think JAI is opening a stream on second argument of create method, without closing it ...

Comment: There is no `close()` function for `File` object

Comment: Of course. But JAI.create may open an InputStream without closing it. You have to investigate inside your enigmatic JAI class ...

Answer (score 0):

Well there's definitely no exception since your catch block is empty.

Something may be still holding a handle to the file, not allowing it to be deleted.
I would examine JAI.create, RenderedOp and the TiffEncoder.

Comment: Above code I have just created to post here. My actual code contains Exception print.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing the file path as string you can provide input stream and in finally first close the input stream and then delete the file. This may work.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem sometime before. The best way to do it in this is to first dispose the resources using the image object you have create, like below-

```
var image = Image.FromFile(pngTarget); // here pngTarget is my PNG file's name along with complete path. 

// your code to convert png to tiff

.
.
.
```

at the end of the method you can write below -

```
image.Dispose(); // the image object I have created above
File.Delete(pngTarget); // delete the file
```

Also, don't forget to flush/close the memory stream, if using any.

Thanks.